# Webview displayed insecure content from

Tags: android, ssl, webview

I have implemented web view inside my android app. It is perfectly displaying web pages in android marshmallow, but one device with android 4.1.1 is not displaying pages. I have added this code

```
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed();
        }
```

for SSL error.

But with change also page is not displayed in 4.1.1 device

The page at something.com displayed insecure content from

any help?

Comment: Its Work for You?

Comment: Else need any help?

Comment: This is just a public site and opens perfectly when opened in chrome or chrome custom tab but gives error in webview

Comment: I want to open this page despite the warning, handler.proceed helps in opening pages on higher android versions, but does not work on lower versions

Answer (score 2):

> To Solve Google Play Warning: WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError handler

Not Always force to `handler.proceed();` but you have to also include handler.cancel(); so user can avoid unsafe content from loading.

To Handle unsafe implementation of the WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError handler

use the following code

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new SSLTolerentWebViewClient());
 webView.loadUrl(myhttps url);
```

**Create class with,**

```
private class SSLTolerentWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Tab1Activity.this);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        String message = "SSL Certificate error.";
        switch (error.getPrimaryError()) {
            case SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED:
                message = "The certificate authority is not trusted.";
                break;
            case SslError.SSL_EXPIRED:
                message = "The certificate has expired.";
                break;
            case SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH:
                message = "The certificate Hostname mismatch.";
                break;
            case SslError.SSL_NOTYETVALID:
                message = "The certificate is not yet valid.";
                break;
        }

        message += " Do you want to continue anyway?";
        alertDialog.setTitle("SSL Certificate Error");
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Ignore SSL certificate errors
                handler.proceed();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                handler.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To properly handle SSL certificate validation, change your code to invoke SslErrorHandler.proceed() whenever the certificate presented by the server meets your expectations, and invoke SslErrorHandler.cancel() otherwise.

```
 @Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.notification_error_ssl_cert_invalid);
    builder.setPositiveButton("continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            handler.proceed();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            handler.cancel();
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: This is just a public site and opens perfectly when opened in chrome or chrome custom tab but gives error in webview